# XamarinForms XAML: How can I inherit properties from another XAML file like ResourceDictionaries?

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Resource Dictionaries a lot, but it's getting tedious having to copy and paste them from one Xaml to the other to have them all update. The only way I've seen this done is inheriting a style class, but I do not like the way properties are declared in C# (I prefer the more visual tree syntax of XAML). Is there some way to have one XAML inherit from another? or a method like LoadXaml() that I can call on each Xamarin.Forms.ContentPage I create to inherit from a StylePage?

Here is my style xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="Demo.StylePage">
    <!-- Shared Properties -->
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- TitleBar Styles -->
            <Style x:Key="TitleBarStyle" TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#5db3d6"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="15,6"/>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="44"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="TitleBarHeaderStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand"/>
<!--                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>-->
                <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand"/>
            </Style>

            <Style x:Key="EmptyFrameStyle" TargetType="Frame">
                <Setter Property="HasShadow" Value="false"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
</ContentPage>
```

How could I load this resource dictionary from another file? Thank you for your time, Sergei.

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Global_Styles_using_Application_Resources

Comment: I already checked this out, and it creates Resource Dictionaries using C#, exactly what I didn't want. I'm looking for a way to import Resource Dictionaries from XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your App.cs with a XAML/cs combo as shown [here](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/styles/#Using_Xaml_for_your_App)

The resources defined in your App.xaml will be available for every view loaded in your app.

Make sure your App.xaml file has a build action of "Embedded Resource". Alternatively you can add it as a `ContentView with XAML` from the UI and then replace `ContentView` with `Application`

[image]

**App.xaml**

```
<Application
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="WorkingWithAppResources.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="labelStyle" TargetType="Label">
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Green" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        MainPage = YourContentPage(); // change as required
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a n error on the InitializeComponent() line saying  "it doesn't exist on the current context". How did you do this?

Comment: did you make the .xaml an embedded resource? check the answer again, I added suggestions on how to avoid this error. Try running "clean" on the solution or delete bin and obj folders and try rebuilding

Comment: This works, altough not exactly what I wanted since this way I can only have one global style. It would have been nice to have some pages inherit from one style page, and some from another, but I'll mark this as right answer since it's the one that cleared this roadblock for now. If you have any links or resources that actually let me inherit pages from a basePage it would be greatly appreciated (It has something to do with that partial classes don't let me specify a base class I think)

Answer (score 3):

ContentPages support inheritance. You can always define one BasePage, implement your resources there, and then have each new ContentPage inherit it. While I've never done this with inheriting xaml, I have used to share analytics, logging, etc. in my BasePage's code-behind (as shown below).

I'd suggest trying a similar approach and just instantiating your resource dictionary in your BasePage.

BaseFormPage:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
    {
        public BasePage () : base () { }

        protected override void OnAppearing ()
        {
            base.OnAppearing ();

            AnalyticsApi.LogPageView ();
            AnalyticsApi.LogEvent(Title + " Page Loaded");

        }
    }
```

ChildFormPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<local:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApp;assembly=MyApp"
             x:Class="MyApp.LoginPage"
             Title="{x:Static local:Strings.SignIn}"
             BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:Colors.ThemeQuaternary}">
    <StackLayout>
        ...
    </StackLayout>
</local:BasePage>
```

Comment: I tried this but got an error trying to inherit from your BaseFormPage, saying "partial declarations must not specify different base classes". Any ideas?

Comment: I just realized that I wrote BaseForm in instead of BasePage (which the child page expects). You may also need to go into the generated file for each ContentPage to give it a "kick start" as to which class you want to inherit from. i.e. delete : ContentPage from the generated file and replace it with : BasePage

Comment: I got a bit lost, could you provide a really simple example of one ChildPage ContentPage class inheriting from a BasePage ContentPage class and getting access to it's resource dictionary? Sorry...I'm trying and doing a lot of versions on my project but none work

Answer (score 0):

In `Xamarin.Forms`, you can declare resources on every `VisualElement`. You then access those resources using either `{StaticResource}` or `{DynamicResource}`.

The resolution rules applied are roughly as follows:

- for `{StaticResource}`:

  - Look in this `VisualElement.Resources` or any of its parent **in the same `XAML` file**
  - Then look in `Application.Current.Resources`
- for `{DynamicResource}`:

  - Look in this `VisualElement.Resources` or any of its parent, even the ones not defined in the same `XAML` file, and up to the `Application.Resources`
  - note that `{DynamicResources}` supports adding resources later, or changing parents

To answer your question, you can indeed define your Styles in a base class in `XAML` and use `XAML` inheritance, or add all your resources to your Application class. If you don't have a `XAML` file for your Application, just add one, and call `InitializeComponents()` from the Application constructor.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example on how to load a say... "BaseStylePage.xaml" into a ChildPage.xaml? I'm trying to do this but I get  "partial declarations must not specify different base classes" when trying to inherit